# What is the right way assign an array in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue.js store with an array and a mutation that sets it after is is reloaded via an API:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    triggeredTests: [],
  mutations: {
    setTriggeredTest(state, data) {
      state.triggeredTests = _
        .chain(data)
        .forEach((item) => {
          item.dateFormatted = moment(item.date).format('DD MMMM YYYY');
          item.explanationTest = testMapping.get(item.test);
        })
        .orderBy('date')
        .groupBy('date')
        .value();
    },
  },
});
```

Should I use some specific [mutation method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods) to assign the array here to make the bound components refresh correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `triggeredTests` property is already in the store (via `state:`) so Vue has added change listeners and `state.triggeredTests = newArray` triggers a change.

You only need `Vue.set(state, 'triggeredTests', newArray)` when a property was not known before.

However changes may not be visible inside a Component that only listens to changes to an item in the previous array.

Using [mapState()](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) and using the `triggeredTests` variable you'll make sure changes to the array are reflected in the component.

```
computed: mapState({
   item: state => state.triggeredTests.find( ... )
})
```

Comment: What about the performance of state.triggeredTests.find( ... ) ?

Comment: Vue is smart about recomputing computed properties and javascript is really fast, but it's faster if you can lookup them up directly `state => state.entities[this.id]`. Then you'll likely need to use `Vue.set(state.entities, id, item)` in your stores.

Answer (score 0):

If you are resetting the entire array you can use Vue.Set() and create a copy of the array. Below is a rough version of this:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
  triggeredTests: [],
},
mutations: {
    MUTATE_ITEMS: (state, items) => {
        Vue.set(state, 'items', [items]);
    }
},
actions: {
    loadTriggeredTests: (context, data) => {
        const newTriggeredTests = array1.map(item => {
            return {
                dateFormatted : moment(item.date).format('DD MMMM YYYY'),
                explanationTest : testMapping.get(item.test)
            }
        });

        context.commit("MUTATE_ITEMS", newTriggeredTests);
    }
}
});
```